# R: 3D surface plot directory issue

Tags: r

i want to plot the bi-variate surface chart of sepal.length and sepal.width data. i tried the following code:

```
library(ISLR)
library(MASS)
library(plotly)
attach(iris)
gd <- kde2d(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, n = 50)
x, y = dg$y, z = dg$z) %>% addrt <- plot_ly(x = dg$_surface()
rt
```

i was expecting a surface chart but the following error message occured:

> Error in getExportedValue(pkg, name) : 
>     cannot open file '~/R/win-library/3.3/viridisLite/data/Rdata.rdb': No such file or directory
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In getExportedValue(pkg, name) : restarting interrupted promise evaluation

i have checked the directory and file the "Rdata.rdb". none of them is missing. please give me a solution.

Comment: This is not reproducible (or valid) R code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@– Roman Luštrik 
previous code was not right. but the following is.

```
 rd <- kde2d(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length, n = 50)
    irdp <- plot_ly(x = rd$x, y = rd$y, z = rd$z) %>% add_surface()
irdp
```